# Proving a set identity: $\left(\bigcap A_\alpha\right)^c = \bigcup A_{\alpha}^c$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If $A \subseteq X$ and $A_{\alpha}$ is a collection of all such subsets, I need to prove that:

$$\left(\bigcap_{\text{all }\alpha} A_\alpha\right)^c = \bigcup_{\text{all }\alpha} A_{\alpha}^c$$

My attempt:

$$\text{Step 1: }A^c = \{ x : x \in X, x \not \in A \}$$
So,
$$\text{Step 2: } \left(\bigcap_{\text{all }\alpha} A_\alpha\right)^c = 
\{ x:  x \in X, x \not \in \{x : x \in X, x \in A_1 \wedge x \in A_2 \wedge\cdots \}\}$$ 
$$= \{x : x \not \in A_1 \vee x \not \in A_2 \vee x \not \in A_3 \vee \cdots\}$$

Similarly,

$$\text{Step 3: } \bigcup_{\text{all }\alpha} A_\alpha^c = \{ x: x \in A_1 \wedge x \in A_2 \wedge x \in A_3 \wedge \cdots \}$$

I understand that if I want to show that $A = B$, I need to show that $A \subseteq B$ and that $B \subseteq A$.

But I'm not sure how to relate step 2 to step 3.

Also, is the direct jump from step 1 to 2 justified. Or do I need an intermediate step?

Comment: Isn't this just Demorgan's law?

Comment: You can's write $A_1,A_2,A_3,\cdots$ like that, this implies every set can be well ordered. Instead, you should use the logical quantifier "for all" and "there exists". Every set notion has some corresponding logical notion. You can think about that.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible hint: given $\cup_\alpha A_\alpha = X$, show that $\cup_\alpha A_\alpha^c = X$ (take $A = \emptyset$, find $A^c$, then think about the union of every set with $A^c$). Next hint: $A \cap B \subseteq A$, take $A = \emptyset$ again and reason about the complement of the intersection.

P.s.: I'm assuming that you're considering every set of $2^X$.

Answer (score 0):

$x\in (\bigcap_\alpha A_\alpha)^c$

iff NOT $x\in\bigcap_\alpha A_\alpha$

iff NOT for all $\alpha$, $x\in A_\alpha$

iff there exists $\alpha$, NOT $x\in A_\alpha$

iff there exists $\alpha$, $x\in A_\alpha^c$

iff $x\in\bigcup_\alpha A_\alpha^c$

You should also read this symbolism:

$x\in (\bigcap_\alpha A_\alpha)^c\leftrightarrow x\notin\bigcap_\alpha A_\alpha\leftrightarrow\lnot\forall\alpha(x\in A_\alpha)\leftrightarrow\exists\alpha(x\notin A_\alpha)\leftrightarrow\exists\alpha(x\in A_\alpha^c)\leftrightarrow x\in\bigcup_\alpha A_\alpha^c$